# Load Icon from firebase and set it as Icon for BottomNavigationBar

Tags: android, android-studio, icons, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to load an Icon dinammically into my Bottom Navigation Bar.
Each time, the user clicks a new variable (in my case a new city) the icon for the variable shall be downloaded from the firebase server and be set to the bottom navigation bar.
My code till now looks like this:

```
// first I load the relevant Icon from firebase
iconRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child(city);
    iconRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            cityIcon = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

// this is for initiating bottom navigation bar
bottomNavigationView = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_nav);
Menu menu = bottomNavigationView.getMenu();

// the following shall load the Id of the part in the bottom navigation bar, where the icon shall be passed to
ImageView iconView = findViewById(R.id.CityIcon);
Picasso.get().load(cityIcon).into(iconView);
menuItemCity.setTitle(cCity);
// the problem is, when I start the activity it crashes
```

Alternatively I thought this could help me:

```
// but the following gives me an error as I am only allowed to enter an Integer and I am entering a String 
MenuItem menuItemCity = menu.getItem(0);
menuItemCity.setIcon(cityIcon);
```

I was also thinking about first saving all the icons into the drawable folder. But as I want to be able to change the Icons after launch of the App it wouldn't serve my requirements. Though there might be a possibility to save the Icons into the drawable folder after downloading them from the server - maybe some of you people have any ideas how to solve this problem.